# limit disk space used by vps

Tags: debian, vps, disk-space-utilization, quota

I got a VPS on Debian and I often tend to run into an issue with disk space. I got a huge error log generated or a huge backup etc and I max out the disk space and that causes mysql to stop working.

How can I limit my vps disk usage to say, 90%? This way even if I max it out the mysql could work properly. I'm not sure I explained it correctly.

Comment: Partition the disk(s), and put MySQL's data on its own dedicated partition.

Comment: Or put /var/log on its own partition... or set up logrotate so it rotates logs based on size

Answer (score -2):

We have options to restrict with user access and mount points. But for production servers, we can play with Monitoring tools like Nagios.so we will have heads ups with disk-usage

Comment: how does this answer the question?